# What does second order variable mean?

Tags: logic, higher-order-logic

What exactly does second-order variable mean? I know that first order variable (usually denoted by lower case letters like $p,q,r...$) are those which take the value $T$(true) or $F$(false). I see that second-order variable are usually denoted by higher case letters (like $X,Y...$).

I at first thought that the *second* order was concerned with the arity of the relation, like unary relation(set) or binary relation(like the edge relation in Graphs). But then when I saw the definition of [monadic second order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monadic_second-order_logic), I was surprised to know that second order variable can be unary. I am too confused and would really appreciate some help in understanding what exactly a *second order variable* means?

Comment: Usually a first order variable (in a set theory) is a variable that represents an element of a set.  A second order variable is a variable that represents a set.  So, you can say "For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$" and get a first order variable.  And, you can say "For all $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$" and get a second order variable.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. So I guess what makes a second order variable $X$ unary or binary or ternary is whether $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ or $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ or $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{3}$. Am I right?

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 While set theory more or less models a(n untyped) higher order logic, it is itself a theory in first-order logic. $X$ in $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is still a first order variable as this is completely equivalent to $X\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ in typical presentations of set theory. That said, elements of powersets, i.e. subsets, model predicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly.

First-order variables, usually: $x,y,z,\ldots$ stand for "objects".

Second-order variables, usually: $X,Y,Z,\ldots$ stand for "properties" of objects, like relations.

Example: the (second-order) [Axiom of induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Axiom_of_induction) :

> $\forall P \ [P(0) \land \forall k \ (P(k) \to P(k+1)) \to \forall n \ P(n)]$.

In this case, $k,n$ are first-order variables, ranging over *numbers*: the objects of the domain, while $P$ is a second-order (and unary) variable, ranging over *properties* of numbers.

See [Second-order and Higher-order Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/).

---

The *order* of a property (or predicate) is its "level" in the hierarchy of objects-properties of objects-properties of properties of objects, and so on.

It is not the *arity* of a predicate symbol.

The *arity* of a predicate or relation (in logic represented by *predicate* symbols) is the number of its argument places.

A *unary* predicate is e.g "even": $\text {even}(x)$.

A *binary* predicate is e.g. "less than" : $<(x,y)$, usually written (for readibility): $x < y$.

A *ternary* predicate is e.g "between" : $\text {between}(x,y,z)$, meaning: $y \text { lies between } x \text { and } z$

The unary predicate $\text {even}(x)$ defines also a set, the set of even numbers: $\{ n \mid \text {even}(n) \}$.

And the binary predicate $<$ defines a (binary) relation, i.e. a set of couples: $\{ (n,m) \mid n < m \}$

Comment: And third-order variables $\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y},\dots$ stand for sets of sets.

Comment: So, what JoeJohnson said in his comment is also right, right? For even($x$) is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ and lessThan($y$) a subset of $\mathbb{N}^{2}$. Thank you for the link by the way. It's the thing I needed.

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre No, ${\rm lessThan}(x,y)$ characterizes a subset of $\mathbb{N}^2$ . It is not clear what you mean by  ${\rm lessThan}(y)$, but in any case it a _unary_ predicate.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant $(x,y)$, not $x$. But how come it is an unary predicate? Even the answer says it is a binary predicate.

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre - I think he means that $\text {lessThan}(y)$ is *unary*, while of course $\text {lessThan}(x,y)$ is *binary*. Of course, it is not a good practice to use the same name for two different predicates...